# Visualizing XYZ data in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: 3d, arcgis-pro, geology, visualisation

I am pretty new to ArcGis Pro and would like to import (near surface geophysical data) which are available as x/y/z/p(arameter/value). The x/y locations are in UTM so no local coordinate system is needed to work around.
I am sure this is possible but couldn't find anything on the ArcGis ressources page.

Comment: Firstly you need create file with delimiter (csv, or excel file). Then add to arcmap. There is button for Add XY Data. Click on it and it will visualize z-value. Here is a link: https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/04/28/xyz-file-into-arcmap/

Answer (score 1):

1. Save the file as a CSV or excel sheet with the four columns (x,y,z,p)
2. Go to ArcScene use add x,y data from file menu, add data option.
3. Use the appropriate columns for x,y, z values
4. After adding the data to the map , right click on the corresponding layer and select properties.
5. In the properties there is a tab for base heights. In that use elevation from values in the layer's features. This will render the layer in 3 dimension.
6. Use the symbology section and choose appropriate colours based on the 'p' attribute for rendering the colours based on parameters.